# How to get the current url of html page using phonegap

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I am using jquery, jquery mobile and html to build a mobile app using phonegap, my index.html display a list of names

```
 <li><a href="profile.html?id='+item.id+'"><h3>'+item.fname+' '+item.lname+'</h3></a></li>
```

When user click on any person of list, the profile of that person should be displayed, 
I need to get the current url (profile.html?id=) to extract the id of the person, to make the database query.

I tried to use ( inside the body of profile.html)

```
<script> 
 url=window.location.href;
<script>
```

and

```
   <script>
    url=document.URL;
    </script>
```

but both return the url of the index.html not the second page (profile.html?id=), even though the URL of page is changed to profile.html?id=2 when I tested on browser any idea?

Comment: u might want this
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: @Vicky Gonsalves Thank you, actually my problem wasn't how to get url query values, but to get the current url so to do ( The debug was showing the previous page url). 
Well, the question updated with the solution.

Comment: You can add that solution as an answer below and accept it, so that this question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After too many attempts and searches, found the solution, using

```
$.mobile.activePage[0].baseURI;
```

According to Alex Bachuk, using window.location.href will return previous page URL, while active page is inserted into the DOM via AJAX, we need to use mobile.activePage[0] to get the current page URL.

sources: http://alexbachuk.com/jquery-mobile-active-page-url/